# How to convert string representation of tensors into numpy array in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pytorch

I have a pandas df containing prediction probability distributions from a torch model. It looks like this:

```
    Framecount  Expression                                        Probability
0          0.0         8.0  tensor([6.9263e-06, 6.6337e-10, 8.2442e-03, 4....
11        10.0         8.0  tensor([6.4393e-05, 4.4693e-07, 8.2253e-02, 1....
22        20.0         9.0  tensor([7.5355e-05, 2.4437e-07, 9.7638e-02, 1....
33        30.0         3.0  tensor([4.9751e-05, 1.1386e-06, 4.7163e-03, 7....
44        40.0         9.0  tensor([1.3237e-05, 1.3779e-07, 2.8534e-03, 1....
```

When I run `type(df.Probability.tolist()[0])`, I get `str`. Why is this?

How can I convert this column to contain arrays of floats so that I can do numerical operations on them?

#### edit

When I create the df, I essentially do the follow:

```
d = []
framecount = 0

for x in data:
    Expression = model.predict(x)[0] # 8.0
    Probability = model.predict(x)[1] # tensor([6.9263e-06, 6.6337e-10, 
...
    d.append([framecount, Expression, Probability])
    framecount += 10

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: How do you create this dataframe? Please show some relevant code so we can help you.

Comment: I made some edits, hope that clarifies.

Comment: Just convert them to numpy using `Probability.cpu().numpy()`

Comment: @AnuragReddy do you mean to do this conversion in the for loop before creating the df? How can I do this conversion after making the df?

Comment: Before converting the I would recommend in or above the line `d.append([framecount, Expression, Probability])`

Comment: @AnuragReddy I see, thank you. But how do I make this conversion after the df was already created so I don't have to reprocess my data again?

Comment: Ooh now I see, when you read that column and check its `dtype`, what does it show?

Comment: @AnuragReddy dtype('O')

Comment: I ended up doing this, but I'm sure there is a more elegant way: `import ast
l = []
for i in df.Probability.tolist():
    l.append(np.asarray(ast.literal_eval(i[7:-1].replace('\n', '').replace('        ', ' '))))`

`
df.prob = l

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221892/discussion-between-anurag-reddy-and-connor449).

Comment: Are you also loading this frame from a `csv` file?  If so, what does the file look like?